# Programmatically Seperate Added Emails to CC in Reports

Tags: acumatica

I have code which returns all contacts belonging to a customer's contact list in a specific mailing ID. The code inserts all of the names inside of the CC portion of the e-mail when the user clicks "Send" when viewing a report. The problem is that the code does not separate the e-mails out properly as if someone manually puts the e-mails in by hand.

This is how it puts the e-mails into the CC slot programmatically:
[image]

And this is how I would like it to add the e-mails properly:
[image]

The way I currently build the string that is returned is as follows:

```
emails += "\"\"" + contact.FullName + "\" (" + contact.EMail + ") <" + 
   contact.EMail + ">\"\r"; //Environment.NewLine;
```

I did try newline, but that didn't work, so I just used \r and left in the newline commented out.

Comment: Which Email client are you targeting? I think you should refer to your email client documentation for the proper way to separate Email addresses. Outlooks recommends the use of a semi-colon ';' as recipient separator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Acumatica email client, I suggest using semi-colon as a separator.

The email address will span multiple lines if there is insufficient space.

Ex: ""Test" (DR@acumatica.com)"; ""Test2" (DR2@acumatica.com)"; ""Test3" (DR3@acumatica.com)"

[image: email address separator configuration]
[image: email address separator]

Comment: That worked! I forgot that e-mails are typically semicolon separated.